# Mac m1 Cmake :The C compiler "/usr/bin/clang" is not able to compile a simple test program

Tags: macos, cmake, clang, clang++, arm64

I want to use `Cmake` to build a `QT` project. However, I don't know what I modify as a reault that the simplest project can not be built with `Cmake`. I believe that this project can be built with `Cmake` before.
Here are the `Cmakelists.txt`, source files and error information.

`Cmakelists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(test VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(test main.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

`main.cpp`

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    
    int main(int, char**) {
        std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    }
```

`error information`

````
The C compiler identification is AppleClang 14.0.0.14000029
The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 14.0.0.14000029
Detecting C compiler ABI info

Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang
Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang - broken
CMake Error at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.24.0/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
The C compiler
> 
>     "/usr/bin/clang"
> 
> is not able to compile a simple test program.
> 
> It fails with the following output:
> 
> Change Dir: /Users/luzijian/Documents/document/AFTE/project_waterLocalize/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
> 
> Run Build Command(s):/Users/luzijian/Documents/Environment/Anaconda3/anaconda3/bin/ninja cmTC_4eeba && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_4eeba.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
> [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_4eeba
> FAILED: cmTC_4eeba 
>     : && /usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names /opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt/6.3.1_1/lib CMakeFiles/cmTC_4eeba.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_4eeba   && :
> ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt/6.3.1_1/lib' for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)
> 
> 
> Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
> See also "/Users/luzijian/Documents/document/AFTE/project_waterLocalize/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
> See also "/Users/luzijian/Documents/document/AFTE/project_waterLocalize/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".



`CMakeOutput.log`

```
> The system is: Darwin - 22.3.0 - arm64
> Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
> Compiler: /usr/bin/clang
> Build flags:
> Id flags:
> 
> The output was:
> 0
> 
> Compilation of the C compiler identification source "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.out"
> The C compiler identification is AppleClang, found in "/Users/luzijian/Documents/document/AFTE/project_waterLocalize/test/build/CMakeFiles/3.24.0/CompilerIdC/a.out"
> 
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
> Compiler: /usr/bin/clang++
> Build flags:
> Id flags:
> 
> The output was:
> 0
> 
> 
> Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.out"
> 
> The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang, found in "/Users/luzijian/Documents/document/AFTE/project_waterLocalize/test/build/CMakeFiles/3.24.0/CompilerIdCXX/a.out"
> 
> ```
> `CMakeError.log`
> 
> ```
> Detecting C compiler ABI info failed to compile with the following output:
> Change Dir: /Users/luzijian/Documents/document/AFTE/project_waterLocalize/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
> 
> Run Build Command(s):/Users/luzijian/Documents/Environment/Anaconda3/anaconda3/bin/ninja cmTC_d5811 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_d5811.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o
> Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
> Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
> Thread model: posix
> InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
> clang: warning: -Wl,-v: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
>  "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple arm64-apple-macosx12.3.0 -Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_ -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-is
> clang -cc1 version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102) default target arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
> ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/local/include"
> ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
> #include "..." search starts here:
> #include <...> search starts here:
>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include
>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include
>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
> End of search list.
> [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_d5811
> FAILED: cmTC_d5811 
> : && /usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names /opt/homebrew/li
> Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
> Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
> Thread model: posix
> InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
>  "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dyli
> @(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-819.6
> BUILD 21:47:32 Sep 13 2022
> configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em
> Library search paths:
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib
> Framework search paths:
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
> ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/opt/homebrew/lib' for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
> 
> 
> 
> Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
> Change Dir: /Users/luzijian/Documents/document/AFTE/project_waterLocalize/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
> 
> Run Build Command(s):/Users/luzijian/Documents/Environment/Anaconda3/anaconda3/bin/ninja cmTC_9af4a && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_9af4a.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
> [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_9af4a
> FAILED: cmTC_9af4a 
> : && /usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names /opt/homebrew/li
> ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/opt/homebrew/lib' for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed. 
> 
> 
> 
> Detecting C compiler ABI info failed to compile with the following output:
> Change Dir: /Users/luzijian/Documents/document/AFTE/project_waterLocalize/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
> 
> Run Build Command(s):/Users/luzijian/Documents/Environment/Anaconda3/anaconda3/bin/ninja cmTC_20350 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_20350.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o
> Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
> Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
> Thread model: posix
> InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
> clang: warning: -Wl,-v: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
>  "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple arm64-apple-macosx12.3.0 -Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_ -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-is
> clang -cc1 version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102) default target arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
> ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/local/include"
> ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
> #include "..." search starts here:
> #include <...> search starts here:
>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include
>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include
>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
> End of search list.
> [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_20350
> FAILED: cmTC_20350
> : && /usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names /opt/homebrew/li
> Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
> Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
> Thread model: posix
> InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
>  "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dyli
> @(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-819.6
> BUILD 21:47:32 Sep 13 2022
> configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em
> Library search paths:
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib
> Framework search paths:
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
> ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/opt/homebrew/lib' for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
> 
> Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
> Change Dir: /Users/luzijian/Documents/document/AFTE/project_waterLocalize/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
> 
> Run Build Command(s):/Users/luzijian/Documents/Environment/Anaconda3/anaconda3/bin/ninja cmTC_eb747 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_eb747.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
> [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_eb747
> FAILED: cmTC_eb747
> : && /usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names /opt/homebrew/li
> ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/opt/homebrew/lib' for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
> 
> Detecting C compiler ABI info failed to compile with the following output:
> Change Dir: /Users/luzijian/Documents/document/AFTE/project_waterLocalize/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
> 
> Run Build Command(s):/Users/luzijian/Documents/Environment/Anaconda3/anaconda3/bin/ninja cmTC_12589 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_12589.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o
> Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
> Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
> Thread model: posix
> InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
> clang: warning: -Wl,-v: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
>  "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple arm64-apple-macosx12.3.0 -Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_ -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-is
> clang -cc1 version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102) default target arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
> ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/local/include"
> ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
> #include "..." search starts here:
> #include <...> search starts here:
>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include
>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include
>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
> End of search list.
> [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_12589
> FAILED: cmTC_12589
> : && /usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names /opt/homebrew/li
> Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
> Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
> Thread model: posix
> InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
>  "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dyli
> @(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-819.6
> BUILD 21:47:32 Sep 13 2022
> configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em
> Library search paths:
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib
> Framework search paths:
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
> ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/opt/homebrew/lib' for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
> 
> 
> Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
> Change Dir: /Users/luzijian/Documents/document/AFTE/project_waterLocalize/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
> 
> Run Build Command(s):/Users/luzijian/Documents/Environment/Anaconda3/anaconda3/bin/ninja cmTC_11d39 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_11d39.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
> [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_11d39
> FAILED: cmTC_11d39
> : && /usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names /opt/homebrew/li
> ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/opt/homebrew/lib' for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
> 
> 
> 
> Detecting C compiler ABI info failed to compile with the following output:
> Change Dir: /Users/luzijian/Documents/document/AFTE/project_waterLocalize/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
> 
> Run Build Command(s):/Users/luzijian/Documents/Environment/Anaconda3/anaconda3/bin/ninja cmTC_a4698 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_a4698.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o
> Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
> Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
> Thread model: posix
> InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
> clang: warning: -Wl,-v: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
>  "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple arm64-apple-macosx12.3.0 -Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_ -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-is
> clang -cc1 version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102) default target arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
> ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/local/include"
> ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
> #include "..." search starts here:
> #include <...> search starts here:
>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include
>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/include
>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
>  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
> End of search list.
> [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_a4698
> FAILED: cmTC_a4698
> : && /usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names /opt/homebrew/Ce
> Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
> Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.3.0
> Thread model: posix
> InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
>  "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dyli
> @(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-819.6
> BUILD 21:47:32 Sep 13 2022
> configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em
> Library search paths:
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/usr/lib
> Framework search paths:
>     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
> ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt/6.3.1_1/lib' for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
> 
> Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
> Change Dir: /Users/luzijian/Documents/document/AFTE/project_waterLocalize/test/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
> 
> Run Build Command(s):/Users/luzijian/Documents/Environment/Anaconda3/anaconda3/bin/ninja cmTC_4eeba && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_4eeba.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
> [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_4eeba
> FAILED: cmTC_4eeba
> : && /usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names /opt/homebrew/Ce
> ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt/6.3.1_1/lib' for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
>
````

This error occurred after I modify the `IntelliSense Configurations` of C++ in VScode and it will generate a `c_cpp_properties.json`. I don't know if it is related to the error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h330J.png)

And I also modify the `~/.bash_profile`

```
conda initialize >>>
Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!

__conda_setup="$('/Users/luzijian/Documents/Environment/Anaconda3/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
 if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
 eval "$__conda_setup"
 else
 if [ -f "/Users/luzijian/Documents/Environment/Anaconda3/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
         . "/Users/luzijian/Documents/Environment/Anaconda3/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
 else
 export PATH="/Users/luzijian/Documents/Environment/Anaconda3/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
 fi  
 fi
 unset __conda_setup
 conda initialize <<<
 
 #vim
 export "PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
 
 export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt/6.3.1_1/bin:$PATH"
 export LDFLAGS="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt/6.3.1_1/lib"
 export CPPFLAGS="-I//opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt/6.3.1_1/include"
 export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt/6.3.1_1/lib/PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
 
 #zsh
 export CLICOLOR=1
 export LSCOLORS=ExGxFxdaCxDaDahbadeche
 
 #alias qmake
 alias qmake="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt/6.3.1_1/bin/qmake"
```

```
`~/.zshrc`
```

```
conda initialize >>>
Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
 __conda_setup="$('/Users/luzijian/Documents/Environment/Anaconda3/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
 if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
 eval "$__conda_setup"
 else
 if [ -f "/Users/luzijian/Documents/Environment/Anaconda3/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
         . "/Users/luzijian/Documents/Environment/Anaconda3/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
 else
 export PATH="/Users/luzijian/Documents/Environment/Anaconda3/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
 fi  
 fi
 unset __conda_setup
 conda initialize <<<
 export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.5_1/bin:$PATH"
 
 export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt/6.3.1_1/bin:$PATH"
 export LDFLAGS="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt/6.3.1_1/lib"
 export CPPFLAGS="-I//opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt/6.3.1_1/include"
 export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt/6.3.1_1/lib/PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
 
 source ~/.bash_profile
```

I hope someone can help me solve the problem and I will appreciate it extremely!

Comment: `export LDFLAGS="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt/6.3.1_1/lib"` - This is incorrect linker flags specification. If you wanted to specify directory for search libraries, then you forgot `-L` option before the directory.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Wow! Seemly, I have solved this problem after add the `-L` option. Thanks for your advice!!

Comment: Glad you found a solution. Now scroll all the way down and post an answer. You will be able to accept it after two days. Next time you ask, please narrow your question down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Friedrich Sorry, I did not check the message. I will post an answer right now, and thank you for your reminder.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved that problem.

It's the file `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.zshrc` where I use wrong linker flags specification.

The statement

```
export LDFLAGS="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt/6.3.1_1/lib"
```

should **add `-L` option** to like the following

```
export LDFLAGS=-L"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/qt/6.3.1_1/lib"
```